# Press Enter Key to send the values ​from Form to modal

Tags: javascript, php

```
<form  action="#exampleModal" method="post" id="new_group" onsubmit="submit_handler()">
      <div class="control-group">
           <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                 <label class="fonts">IDCARD</label>
                     <input class="form-control fonts" id="card_id" type="text" name="card_id"placeholder="IDCARD" required="required" minlength="13" maxlength="13" />                                   
                                </div>
                  </div>  
</form>
    
    
  
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display:none" id="exampleModal">
      
            <h5 class="modal-title">Show data</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
     
          <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="container">
    
          <?  
                echo  $_POST["card_id"];
          ?>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <script>
    
    document.getElementById("card_id").addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode === 13) {
          document.getElementById("card_id").submit();
        return false;
        }
    });
    function submit_handler() {
      console.log('modal opened'); //send with ajax?
      $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
      event.preventDefault();
      
      return false;
    }
    
    </script>
```

'Press Enter Key to send the values ​​from Form to modal .'
But now I'm doing both separately. How can I combine them?
'Press Enter Key to send the values ​​from Form to modal .'
But now I'm doing both separately. How can I combine them?

Comment: can you clear the question please

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="#exampleModal" method="post" id="new_group">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls mb-0 pb-2">
                        <label class="fonts">IDCARD</label>
                        <input class="form-control fonts" id="card_id" type="text" name="card_id"placeholder="IDCARD" required="required" minlength="13" maxlength="13"/>                                   
                       </div>
                </div>  
</form>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p id='bodyText'>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
 <script>
document.getElementById("card_id").addEventListener("keypress", function(event) 
{
    if (event.keyCode === 13) 
    {       
    var  cardId = document.getElementById("card_id").value; 
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    document.getElementById("bodyText").innerHTML = cardId;
     event.preventDefault();
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```